# SQL : Having with calculation on some parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, having

I'm currently looking for a way of concidering the value of the difference between some parameters in a HAVING clause.

I explain,

I have a table like :

MyTable

```
id   name    date  
1    john    7/12  
2    doe     7/12  
3    john    7/14  
4    john    9/13  
5    doe     9/14
```

and i want to make a group by like

```
GROUP BY name 
HAVING 'MyTAble[a].date - MyTAble[b].date > 1 month'
```

to have (count) :

```
john (3)  
doe (1)  
john (1)  
doe (1)
```

I know there is a MONTH() function but if I make a group by name, MONTH(date) I will not have the expected result.

I probably miss an obvious solution (or it's just impossible). Anyway, hope you have an idea.

Comment: `MyTAble[a].date - interval 1 month >  MyTAble[b].date`; the syntax may *vary* check the right format for your RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Lacking more information about your query or database engine, I would say that the answer is to use the `where` clause rather than `group by` / `having`. In my experience, `having` is used to limit query results based on the value of an aggregate function, which your `having` clause doesn't use.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm using mysql. Actually I write this exemple to present the general idea. To be more specific it's about notifications : I want to group the notifications by topic (like 'Michael - and more - has commented this topic') but if I only group by topic i will always have 'and more' but if i add a  condition on the date, if someone comment a topic one month later it will be separated of the other notifications. I can give you the entire request but it probably will not be more relevant to explain my problem...

Comment: The approach I would take, then, is to put your `MyTAble[a].date - MyTAble[b].date > 1 month` into the select clause and `order by` it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I guess it's a little bit far-fetched but I found a solution, so I worked on the select clause :

```
SELECT mytable.name name, mytable.date , CONCAT(mytable.name,DAY(mytable.date)) group_id
```

I create an id (group_id) that is common to all the entities I want to gather, then I GROUP BY this common id